# Trying to open date picker dialog when edittext is clicked but its showing an error

Tags: android, android-studio, datepickerdialog

Screenshot of my code has been attached below

I'm trying to open the date picker when the edittext is clicked.but it shows me an error in the first two parameters of the datepickerdialog function.

PARAMETER 1(Context): **Expected:** android.content.Context            **Actual:** this

PARAMETER 2(Listener): **Expected:** android...OnDateSetListener        **Actual:** this

I have attached a screenshot of my code above^

Please and thank you!

[image]

Comment: Hello Nitin, please post the source code as text instead of just the image of it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a different **context** which means you are using this function inside an anonymouse click listener class and when you pass `this` it will take that context not the parent or activity class in your case. just make a small change as below:

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

in short if you say `this` then it will pass the current context which is click listener context in your case and Dialog needs an Activity context so instead use `MainActivity.this` to point to main activity context. In Kotlin this context will be called as `this@MainActivity`

Comment: nice catch I just mixed up things @ljk

Comment: I removed the comment when I realized it was not just kotlin but a combination of both java and kotlin, lol.Glad you fixed it.

Comment: Thanks vikas. it was helpful! :)

Comment: just mark it as answer and upvote if it helps so that other can also get helped from this
thanks